# how to use different version of firefox using webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

how to set Firefox version in web-driver?
I just want to user different version of Firefox.

like different version 19, 20 , 21....

please provide a generic solution which help for other browser also.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to install all the versions on your system. Then you can use the System property `webdriver.firefox.bin` to define the path for Firefox. Note than since the path is set through a System property, you will not be able to run two different Firefox in the same Java process.

This solution is specific to Firefox. There is no generic solution. You have to configure every WebDriver yourself.

More information about the [configuration of Firefox Web Drvier](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver).

Comment: this is not working..:(

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

public void firefoxVersion(){
  
  System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "/Applications/Firefox-2.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin");
  driver.get(baseUrl);
     System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

Comment: You can use different versions in the same run by setting the FirefoxBinary in FirefoxOptions parameter to the FirefoxDriver constructor.

Answer (score 13):

Finally i have found solution to run with different browser version

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "/Applications/Firefox-2.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: thank so so much! you are my new hero, oh great bugCracker sir/mam <3

Answer (score 1):

I have found how to start a different FireFox browser (actually WaterFox) in Python Selenium, replacing

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

with

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary = "/path/to/my/waterfox")
```

(Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.95)