# Runing another firefox.exe than the one used by default with the RemoteWebDriver implementation

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I'm using selenium and i would to use selenium with the firefox.exe from a specific folder and not the one that is already installed. To do so i have the following code :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "./firefox-sdk/bin/firefox.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

    cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(node), cap);
```

The code is working but the problem is it keep running the firefox in the Program Files folder instead of the one in the spcified folder when i use setProperty, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you recompile?

Comment: I'm on eclipse so yes, i guess.

Comment: Well the fact that you are on eclipse isn't a guarantee for that. I do think the green arrow in eclipse compiles and runs your program, but it's been so long since I have used Eclipse that I can not be sure about that

Comment: I'm sure it's recompiled i can see the output changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can launch the firefox version which is not installed in your Program Files.

**Method 1: Using FirefoxBinary**

```
File pathToBinary = new File("./firefox-sdk/bin/firefox.exe");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
cap.setCapability("firefox_binary", pathToBinary);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(node), cap);
```

**Method 2: Using webdriver.firefox.bin property**

In this case you have to install another version of firefox in the above path and then you can set the property `webdriver.firefox.bin` using `System.setProperty()`

Comment: How would i dod the first method with the RemoteWebDriver implementation ? I need it to be the RemoteWebDriver implementation.

Comment: And what you mean by installed ? because yes the files of firefox are in the "./firefox-sdk/" and the .exe is in the "./firefox-sdk/bin/firefox.exe" in my case, i even check if the java code find it, and yes it finds it. But it's like selenium ignore it.

Comment: I've modified my answer to work with `RemoteWebDriver` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have firefox installed into webdriver.firefox.bin directory. This installation and the default installation  must be different.

Please have a look at this thread: [how to use different version of firefox using webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398896/how-to-use-different-version-of-firefox-using-webdriver)

Comment: I did have a look at this thread before writing mine, but i don't get it, what is the webdriver.firefox.bin ? Isn't that enough to have the files of firefox stored somewhere else ?

Comment: Yes it would. But the requirement was to open another instance. We could've done with the same installation as well. In that case, a new profile were needed.