# How to Open two firefox based on firefox path in python selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I want to open Firefox version 32 and 50 on the same system using python selenium version 2.44.

Based on firefox path I want to open firefox browser 32 for first run 50 for the second run.

please, anyone can help on this.

Comment: Are you working with Grid or are you working with normal mode ? You haven't added a lot of information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use different version of firefox using webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398896/how-to-use-different-version-of-firefox-using-webdriver)